# how to skip launch Message for Particular task selected in inno setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

i want to launch program after installation if a user checks a corresponding checkbox (ie;2 install type standalone and service)during the install.i have one checkbox that is for service.so there will be one task only.so normally(by default) it will install as standalone and it will launch one exe after installation.but when i select service,it will show both launch message(ie,standalone and service)to execute after installation. so how to solve this problem?

this is the code that i am using

```
[Tasks]
Name: desktopicon; Description: {cm:CreateDesktopIcon}; GroupDescription: {cm:AdditionalIcons}; Flags: checkedonce
Name: quicklaunchicon; Description: {cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}; GroupDescription: {cm:AdditionalIcons}; Flags: unchecked

; Install for all users or current user only
Name: common; Description: &All users; GroupDescription: Install for:; Flags: exclusive unchecked
Name: local; Description: Just &me; GroupDescription: Install for:; Flags: exclusive
Name: Service; Description:Install as a Service; GroupDescription: Setup Type:; Flags: unchecked

[Run]
Filename: {app}\HMI.exe; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,Runtimne Win32}; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent;
Filename: {app}\ServiceTray.exe; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,Runtimne Win32 as Service}; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent runascurrentuser;Tasks: Service
```

in this normally i want to launch program(ie,runtime win32)if user select service it is showing both launch program message(ie,runtime win32 and runtime win32 as service).i am using only one task ie,service;
so is there any other solution other than using 2 task?

Comment: You're question isn't that clear. Can you try adding sample code and a sample of what you're getting.

Comment: Deanna please help to sove this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the `Launch Runtimne Win32` post install option, add the Task parameter to exclude the Service task:

```
Filename: {app}\HMI.exe; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,Runtimne Win32}; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent; Tasks: Not Service
```